# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS removing column name from results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
USE db183
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING_%' 
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%' THEN 0  
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO_%' THEN 1 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL_%' THEN 2 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING_%' THEN 3
    END, ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
```

And I am wanting to **not include** the column name **EMPINFO_empName**.

However, when trying this:

```
USE db183
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING_%' 
   AND NOT COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_empName' /*<-- NEW ADDED CODE HERE */
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%' THEN 0  
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO_%' THEN 1 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL_%' THEN 2 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING_%' THEN 3
    END, ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
```

Does not seem to take out that particular column name - It's still listed in the output just like the first query.

I'm guessing that I have some syntax incorrect but I do not get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about `information_schema` only.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL_%' 
   OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING_%' ) --this is what you need
   AND NOT COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_empName' /*<-- NEW ADDED CODE HERE */
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Alex!

Comment: The real issue is the order of precedence between **`AND`** and **`OR`**. Using parens around conditions allows us to override the default order of precedence. We should also point out that the underscore character is a *wildcard* in the LIKE condition. That underscore will match any one character.

Comment: this is the same as `2 + 3 * 4` vs `(2 + 3) * 4`

Comment: Are you certain this query does what you think?  Wouldn't those underscores be interpreted as wildcards?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In this case it doesn't matter provided there is no column `EMPINFO2empName` you want to include. Correct code should be `like '%[_]empName'`

Comment: Doing **SCHEDULE_%** or **SCHEDULE[_]%** results in the same results coming back so yes, it does work.

Comment: It may work, but you used the `_` thinking it was the literal character.  There is no difference semantically between `LIKE 'SCHEDULE_%'` and `LIKE 'SCHEDULE%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the underscore in your `LIKE` statement:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SCHEDULE[_]%' OR
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'AVAIL[_]%' OR
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TRAINING[_]%' OR
      (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'EMPINFO[_]%' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%[_]empName%')
```

Actually, if you really just want to exclude a single column then just use the full name:

```
WHERE COLUMN_NAME <> 'EMPINFO_empName'
```

Comment: Still shows up in the query results doing **AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%[_]empName%'**

Comment: And oddly enough, doing **COLUMN_NAME <> 'EMPINFO_empName'** also **does not remove it!**

Comment: Try again.  You need to use brackets around _all_ the underscores in your column names.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev got it correct but thank you as well!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen strictly speaking `_` should be escaped as `[_]` but your Boolean grouping is wrong.

Comment: No, your answer is wrong.  The exclusion only applies to columns with names beginning with `EMPINFO_`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I downvoted. Your speculations about `_` and `[_]` are correct but 1) `_` matches any single char including itself; 2) your Boolean calculation is totally incorrect. `col1 like '...' or col2 like '...' or (col3 NOT like '...' and NOT col3 like '...')` mean let any condition be true. Speculation about the difference between `_` and `[_]` is irrelevant. The difference may occur if there is a column EMPINFO**0**empName which they want to show.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen compare difference `true or false or (false and false)` vs `(true or false) and false`